# Complexity of large matrix multiplication

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication

What is the time complexity of the fastest algorithm known today to multiply large matrices?

What about the theoretical optimal time complexity that could be reached?

Comment: It's important to do some research first before posting questions on SO. Did you try wikipedia?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an active area of research, so this answer may very soon be out of date. :-)

To the best of my knowledge, the current fastest matrix multiplication algorithm runs in time O(n<sup>2.373</sup>), [due to a result by Virginia Williams](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/matrixmult-f.pdf). The algorithm is actually a large family of algorithms that give rise to a complex nonlinear system of equations that give the overall time bound, and in fact there are people doing work right now trying to see how to improve the bound by finding better and better solutions to those equations. I believe that this algorithm is only of theoretical interest, though.

The holy grail of matrix multiplication would be an O(n<sup>2</sup>)-time matrix multiplication algorithm, and whether such an algorithm exists is still an open problem. This is the theoretical limit, since an o(n<sup>2</sup>)-time algorithm couldn't even read all the entries of the matrices to multiply.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup.  Most reasonable people I know expect that matrix multiplication is O(n^2+epsilon).  O(n^2) would be quite surprising.